# What is the best way to discard all your changes (with untracked files) on a git branch?

Tags: git, shell, command-line

Is there a simple command in `git` to remove all changes made to a branch and remove all untracked files? I would like to have a clean branch.

`git checkout` does leave some untracked files and also shows a message that *your files will be overritten*...

`git reset --hard HEAD` also leave untracked files

Comment: Regarding untracked files, you can run `git clean -f` after `git reset --hard HEAD`. However, think twice before using those commands; they're irreversible.

Comment: `git stash --include-untracked` will remove all changes, including untracked files.  You can then drop the stash.  That'd kind of an abuse of the command though.

Comment: But there is no single command to do the above, you would need to add that as a **git alias** ?

Comment: You can take a look at the list of available aliases in [oh-my-zsh git plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh#L69).  There are some good ideas in there, including the one I linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do this with two commands.

From Jubobs<sup>[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679323/what-is-the-best-way-to-discard-all-your-changes-with-untracked-files-on-a-git#comment57103979_34679323)</sup>

```
git reset --hard $rev
git clean -f
```

From R0MANARMY<sup>[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679323/what-is-the-best-way-to-discard-all-your-changes-with-untracked-files-on-a-git#comment57103990_34679323)</sup>

```
git stash --include-untracked
git stash drop
```

Either of those can be aliased to a single command if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to do what you want.

Detailed answer can be found here: [How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-forward-checkout-revet-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)

Another option which is not there and is suitable answer for your question is git clean.

#### git clean

You can do a git clean to remove all the un-tracked files (Backup files)

```
git clean -Xfd // capital X
git clean -xfd // small x
```

> #### -x <sup>(lower case)</sup>
>
> Don’t use the standard ignore rules read from `.gitignore` (per directory) and `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`, but do still use the ignore rules given with -e options.
>
> This allows removing all **untracked files**, including build products.
>   This can be used (possibly in conjunction with git reset) to create a pristine working directory to test a clean build.
>
> #### -X <sup>(uppercase)</sup>
>
> **Remove only files ignored by Git.**
>   This may be useful to rebuild everything from scratch, but keep manually created files.